# How to access map function state and use in external function

Tags: reactjs

I've successfully used the .map function to iterate through the axios GET request data and assign it to the correct element in my map function. However, when I implemented my delete function along with the button onclick element, I receive a the 'Cannot read property '_id' of undefined.

My question is, is it possible to access the map function state of singleuser from my external delete function or to run my delete function within my map function?

```
// Axios GET request to get the object data from users collection
        axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/users')
         .then(response => {
           this.setState({ users: response.data });
         })
         .catch(function (error) {
           console.log(error);
         })

// Delete function referencing the ID of the user 
       delete() {
         axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/users/delete/' + this.state.singleuser._id)
           .then(
              console.log(this.singleuser._id)
           )
           .catch(err => console.log(err))
        }

// Mapping out the state of singleuser from the GET request above          

 {this.state.users.map(function (singleuser, i) {
              const shouldHide = user.group.toString() === singleuser.group.toString()
                 return shouldHide
                    ? null
                    : <tr key={i} style={{ color: '#fff' }}>
                        <td>{singleuser.name}</td>
                        <td>{singleuser.email}</td>
                        <td style={{ display: 'none' }} selected={shouldHide}>{singleuser.group}</td>
                        <td><button onClick={this.delete} className="waves-effect waves-light btn-small red">Edit</button></td>
                      </tr>
             }.bind(this))
            }
```

Comment: You need to update your state after your delete call completes. Then your view will rerender.

Comment: Slightly off topic: If you're trying to use REST, a GET call (`axios.get`) should never delete a resource. Use a DELETE call (`axios.delete`, I assume).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Could you provide a bit more info about updating the state AFTER the delete call?

Comment: In your first call to axios, you have a call to `this.setState({ users: response.data })`, but in the call for delete, you're just logging. You need to do something like `let users = this.state.users; users = users.filter(user => user._id !== this.singleuser._id); this.setState({ users });`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use arrow function, because they don't have a local state
for example

```
   delete = (id) => {
     axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/users/delete/' + id)
       .then((resultOfSuccesfulDeleting) => console.log(resultOfSuccesfulDeleting))
       .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

 {this.state.users.map(function (singleuser, i) {
              const shouldHide = user.group.toString() === singleuser.group.toString()
                 return shouldHide
                    ? null
                    : <tr key={i} style={{ color: '#fff' }}>
                        <td>{singleuser.name}</td>
                        <td>{singleuser.email}</td>
                        <td style={{ display: 'none' }} selected={shouldHide}>{singleuser.group}</td>
                        <td><button onClick={() => this.delete(singleuser._id)} className="waves-effect waves-light btn-small red">Edit</button></td>
                      </tr>
             }.bind(this))
            }
```

Comment: try to change calling a function, because you need to pass needed id to delete, i'll change my answer

Comment: You get an error because you try to get unreal value in state